# Swift UI: How do I display an error message when an empty List is displayed in a View?

Tags: swift, list, user-interface, view, swiftui

I have a collection of `Terms` organized alphabetically into groups. The Swift UI code below displays the collection as a `List` divided into sections by group. Each group is filtered based on a (possibly empty) search string. So the displayed list contains either the whole collection of `Terms`, a subset based on the search string, or nothing (if the search fails):

```
    var body: some View {
        List() {
                        
            ForEach(terms.groups) { group in
                let groupTerms = filteredTerms(for: group)
                
                if searchText.isEmpty || !groupTerms.isEmpty {
                    Section(header: Text(group.name)) {
                        ForEach(groupTerms) { term in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(term: term)) {
                                TermsRow(term: term)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is: how do I display a message that the search failed, as opposed to just an empty screen? It can be determined that the search failed only after the outer `ForEach` loop is completed with all `groupTerms` being empty, but I haven't been able to capture that info -- Swift doesn't like it if I stick a `searchSucceeded` boolean in the `ForEach` loop to set to `true` if any `groupTerms` is non-empty, something like this:

```
    var searchSucceeded = false     
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            
            ForEach(terms.groups) { group in
                let groupTerms = filteredTerms(for: group)
                
                if searchText.isEmpty || !groupTerms.isEmpty {
                    Section(header: Text(group.name)) {
                        ForEach(groupTerms) { term in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(term: term)) {
                                TermsRow(term: term)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  else if !searchText.isEmpty && !groupIdioms.isEmpty {
                    searchSucceeded = true           
                }
            }
            // Display message here if searchSucceeded is false
        }
    }
```

This code won't compile with the assignment to `searchSucceeded` present. I'm a Swift UI newbie. The initial code was written by another developer who's no longer available. I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: SwiftUI is a UI framework. It should never do any work `searchSucceeded = true` counts as work.`let groupTerms = filteredTerms(for: group)` counts as work. Move all "work" code out of a SwiftUI View and put it into a `class ViewModel`. `struct` are immutable `var searchSucceeded = false` this will never be mutated as is. Make it an `@Published var` in your `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to set the `searchSucceeded` inside the `ForEach`, you could make a computed property called `displayError` that determines whether an error should be displayed. The computed property will get recalculated on each render of the view, which would be affected by new properties, @State changes, etc.

```
var displayError : Bool {
    //condition here -- map? reduce?
    return true
}

var body: some View {
    List() {
        ForEach(terms.groups) { group in
            let groupTerms = filteredTerms(for: group)
            if searchText.isEmpty || !groupTerms.isEmpty {
                Section(header: Text(group.name)) {
                    ForEach(groupTerms) { term in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(term: term)) {
                            TermsRow(term: term)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if displayError {
            Text("error message")
        }
    }
}
```

You haven't included your model code, so it's hard to say what to put in that computed property, but looks like from your loop that it'll likely be a `reduce` or something to iterate over your groups and see if there's valid data.

Like @lorem mentioned in the comments, you *can* move this sort of thing to a view model, but it is not strictly necessary. It might become more important if you have a huge amount of data and you want to limit the number of passes through the data for resources reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this - where you have to draw "This" or "That" which are largely different, I use an "EitherView", and a corresponding model "Either":

```
struct EitherView<Right: ComponentView, Left: ComponentView>: ComponentView {
    var state: Either<Right.State, Left.State>

    init(_ state: Either<Right.State, Left.State>) {
        self.state = state
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch state {
        case .right(let right):
            Right(right)
        case .left(let left):
            Left(left)
        }
    }
}
```

```
public enum Either<Right, Left> {
    case right(Right)
    case left(Left)
}
```

You can then add modal presented views and loading indicators like it is shown in the *example* below, which aims to implement a reusable generic view doing all this:

```
struct MyView<ContentView: ComponentView>: View {
    typealias Content = ContentView.State
    typealias Modal = ModalState<AlertState, SheetState, ActionSheetState, LoadingState>
    private var state: ViewState<Content, Modal>

    init(_ state: ViewState<Content, Modal>) {
        self.state = state
    }

    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
        ContentView(state.body)
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
               height: geometry.size.height,
               alignment: .center)
        }
        .alert(item: showAlert) { alert in
            SwiftUI.Alert(title: Text(alert.title),
                          message: Text(alert.message))
        }
        .sheet(item: showSheet) { sheet in
            ...
        }
        .actionSheet(item: showActionSheet) { actionSheet in
            SwiftUI.ActionSheet(title: Text(actionSheet.title))
        }
    }
}
```

```
private extension MyView {
    var showAlert: Binding<AlertState?> {
        Binding<AlertState?>(
            get: { self.state.alert },
            set: { _ in self.state.dismiss() }
        )
    }
  ... 
}
```

Note that view state is not mutable in this example.

In order to apply this to your problem, you just need to compose the corresponding *model* or *viewState*, preferable outside the view, in a viewModel for example.

Now you have separated your big problem into smaller pieces, each of which is easy to solve.